# SMF(SimpleMachineForums) API 2.0

Tags: php, api, forums, simple-machines-forum, smf-forum

Having a little trouble finding the SimpleMachineForums 2.0 API. Its been in beta for about 3 years according to some forum post and the site only has the API up to version 1.1. Does anyone have or know where 2.0 can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that someone has worked out their own:  http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=440504.0

Answer (score 0):

There's a new link to it here:
http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=453008.0

and there is also a quasi-RESTful version of the API as well if anyone else is looking to integrate SMF with something else :)